# Correctly implementing (concurrent) asyncio for multiple functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I have couple of functions and their execution is not dependent each other. What I am trying to do is execute them concurrently instead of sequentially (synchronous). I have added event loop as well, but I am not able to figure out if it is working correctly or not.

This is the implementation:

**File 1:**

```py
import file2

def funcA():
    a, b = 1, 2
    file2.main(a, b)
```

**File2:**

```py
def main(a, b):
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(_main(a, b))

async def _main(a, b):
     out1 = await funcA(a, b)
     out2 = await funcB(a, b)
     out3 = await funcC(a, b)

async def funcA(a, b):
    result = 1 # some processing done here
    return result

async def funcB(a, b):
    result = 1 # some processing done here
    return result

async def funcC(a, b):
    result = 1 # some processing done here
    return result
```

I am not able to figure out if these are working concurrently or not. I am adding `time.sleep(10)` in any function, executions stops there. I don't want them to run in background as I **need output from those functions**.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, async functions that don't `await` anything are most likely a wasted use of async. Unlike threads, asyncio is based on cooperative multitasking, and `await` (along with `async for` and `async with`) is the place where a context switch can happen.

Comment: good info. asyncio is still confusing for me even after trying it multiple times. I followed many tutorials but most of the them will show getting data from urls, instead of showing different examples.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way to do what you want would be to use `asyncio.run()` in `main` and then `gather` in the async version of main. To simulate long processing, use `asyncio.sleep()` See the following code:

```
import asyncio

def main(a, b):
    res = asyncio.run(async_main(a, b))
    print(f"in main, result is {res}")

async def funcA(a, b):
    print('funcA - start')
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    result = (a+b) # some processing done here
    print('funcA - end')

    return result

async def funcB(a, b):
    print('funcB - start')
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    result = (a+b)*2 # some processing done here
    print('funcB - end')
    return result

async def funcC(a, b):
    print('funcC - start')
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    result = (a+b)*3 # some processing done here
    print('funcC - end')

    return result

async def async_main(a, b):
    print("in async_main")
    res = await asyncio.gather(funcA(a, b), funcB(a, b), funcC(a, b))
    print(f"in async_main, result is {res}")
    return res

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(1, 2)
```

The result is:

```
in async_main
funcA - start
funcB - start
funcC - start
funcA - end
funcB - end
funcC - end
in async_main, result is [3, 6, 9]
in main, result is [3, 6, 9]
```

Comment: one doubt, how am I supposed to get the output from funcA, funcB and funcC?

Comment: so in `res = await asyncio.gather(funcA(a, b), funcB(a, b), funcC(a, b))`,  `res` will be a list or tuple, so that I can unpack it to other variables?

Comment: yes. You get the result as a list, in which every element corresponds to one of the function calls - the first element to the first function you were 'gathering', the second to the second, etc. You can now do whatever you want with this list: unpack it, iterate over it, process it, etc.

Comment: (BTW - if the post answers your question, do you mind 'accepting it' as an answer for future generations? )